# How to assign a role to a user automatically when they join?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm using discord.js, and I have searched online for assigning roles to users on join but none of these answers work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', newMember => {
   newMember.addRole(newMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'The role you want to assign'))
})
```